# 1~60 Hz can be used as 50~60 Hz?

Tags: washer, pressure-washer

I purchased a pressure machine of KARCHER for car wash purpose from Saudi Arabia. In the catalogue it is written  1~60Hz whilst in Pakistan 50Hz cycle is used. The question is if the 1~60Hz unit can can be used as 50~60Hz?

If I talk about the machine there is a sticker upon which is written "60Hz". So I am puzzled now if it would be a loss if I take it to Pakistan. It is still new and has not been used.

Answer (score 1):

1~60Hz means 1 (single) phase, 60Hz frequency. Unfortunately, it does not mean 1 to 60 Hz.

Varying frequency is usually written as 50/60Hz, and is less common for electric motors.

It's possible it will work, but it will likely run at a slower rate and may fail early.

Comment: And is more likely to overheat, since more current may flow... *unless* it's a universal motor. If it has brushes and a commutator, it *might* work.